Working from seven to eleven every night
When someone says to you "I work from seven to eleven every night. It really makes life a drag."
What do you usually think his working time is? (from 7AM or from 7PM?)
I thought that since "every night" would modifies both "seven" and "eleven", his working time is 7PM to 11PM. But some person said "his working time is from 7AM to 11PM because if it is from 7PM to 11PM, it is only for 4 hours of labor, not so hard. It would not make life a drag.  So, I think it is from 7AM."
This is about the lyrics of Led Zeppelin‘s  masterpiece "Since I’ve been loving you."
Its lyric begins with the sentence below.

Working from seven to eleven every night.
Really makes life a drag.
I don’t think that’s right.

and later it goes

I’ve been a-working from seven, seven, seven
to eleven every night.
It kinda makes my life a drag

But reading through the lyrics, I think there is no clue to determine whether he works from 7AM or from 7PM, so my question is as mentioned earlier.
When someone says to you "I work from seven to eleven every night. It really makes life a drag." What do you usually think his working hours are, from 7AM or from 7PM?
P.S. If I am told that in person, I will ask him "you mean from 7PM? ". But you know it is a lyric, I can’t do that.

The utterance is not perfectly clear and answers will be opinions only. Life could be a drag if you can never accompany your friends on a night out because you're working to 11PM, whether you started at 7AM or at 7PM.  Or life could be a drag because you're working 16-hour days; or life could be a drag because you're working 11PM to 7AM and are sleep-deprived and cannot even get those numbers in the right order when talking about your job.

Not least because of the alliteration, a seven-eleven has become an established informal term for a local convenience store typically open from 7am to 11pm. But (apart from possibly the "owner-operator" of such a business) you wouldn't normally expect any of the actual staff to work that entire span as a shift. By convention, a "full" working day (in Dolly Parton's song lyrics or in general) is 9 to 5.

In the U.S., 7-11 is a brand of convenience stores. They are typically open 24 hours a day, not from 7am to 11pm. Depending on where you live, you might refer to a convenience store as a 7-11, but that's like calling a tissue a Kleenex.

@TimR I'm surprised by the "opinion" close-votes. I don't see any ambiguity, only guesswork about what's the "drag" (for me, work of any kind in the late evening is unpleasant). I don't know that "7 to 11 every night" could be reasonably understood as am to pm.

@AndyBonner There are "managers" who are hired by companies in the US, especially in the retail sector, who are hired  with "exempt employee" status, which means they are paid a flat salary and don't get paid for overtime, and these employees are often exploited for that status and expected to work very long hours from time to time. It could be that the second-shift manager left, and until a new second-shift manager is hired, the first-shift manager must open the establishment in the morning and close at night.  "I work from 7 to 11 every night" doesn't absolutely mean 7pm-11pm.Normally, yes

Unambiguous would be "I work nights from 7 to 11".

@TimR Sorry, I disagree, and not about the hiring practices but just the phrasing. To my mind, tacking "every night" on the end makes it an unreasonable way of indicating am to pm; if that were intended, I'd want the speaker to clarify e.g. "7 every morning to 11 every night."

@AndyBonner Hiriing practice adduced only to show that 7am to 11pm is not out of the question. The phrase 7 to 11 every evening (without any context) does not entail the meaning 7pm to 11pm, even if that is the likely meaning.  So, as I said above, it's opinion about what it means, and all that one can say is what it probably means or usually means or "almost surely" means.  And that is supposing a usual context or likely context or what most speakers are likely to say.

@TimR Sorry, I'm sticking to my guns. There's no reason for "every night" to modify only one of the two times. It's a common pattern—2 to 4 every Monday, 1 to 3 every day, 7 to 11 every morning. If "every night" were missing, or even if it were "every day" instead, then there would be total ambiguity.

@AndyBonner A person on this website has supported 7 pm to 11 pm. But had given a different meaning to working  https://www.lyricinterpretations.com/led-zeppelin/since-ive-been-loving-you

@JamesMathai An intriguing reading, though not really the OP's point. Since we're focusing on usage on this SE rather than poetry, we might suppose that any similar usage could be substituted ("driving a truck 6 to 10 every night")

In poems (songs too, I think) poets deviate from conventional rules. Since these lines are taken from a song. it's possible correct language is not used.

poetic licence :
noun:
the freedom to depart from the facts of a matter or from the conventional rules of language when speaking or writing in order to create an effect.
"he used a little poetic licence to embroider a good tale"


The language is not incorrect, simply open to interpretation in terms of whether every night indicates that both hours are in the night or only one of them, and in some contexts it could apply to only one of them.  There are clearer ways to say 7pm to 11pm than that.

7am is the morning. 7pm is night.
If you work 7 to 11 every night, your hours are 7pm to 11pm. There's no doubt or ambiguity.
If you work 7 to 11 every morning, your hours are 7am to 11am.
If you work 7 to 11 every day, it's not clear if that's 7 in the morning or 7 at night, so you might have to ask to clarify it.

In the third case, the ambiguity also applies to 11: AM or PM?

I suppose it could, but if you worked 7am to 11pm, you would probably state that specifically, since it's less common and such a long shift. If someone said they worked 7 to 11, I would ask, "is that 7 in the morning or 7 at night?" or I might ask, "7am or 7pm?"

I second this answer. I would expand: the phrase should be parsed "working [from 7 to 11] every night," not "working from [7] to [eleven every night]." In other words, it's all a modification of "working every night."

You're right about the way we tend to resolve the ambiguity, in that we ask if 7 is morning or evening, and once we know that we are likely to also know more about what the 11 refers to. But my point was that from the perspective of interpreting the bare sentence, both times are equally ambiguous.

Who works 16 hours every day ?
I have heard that some people work two eight-hour shifts sometimes.
It is nearly impossible to work everyday in this manner, then their schedule would be work-sleep-work-sleep-work, leaving no time even for basic daily functions.
My explanation.
The song was inspired by another song "Never" which didn't become that popular. The lyricist had changed the line 11 to 7 (meaning a night shift). So the lines may mean 7AM to 11PM or 7PM to 11PM. No need to break our heads finding out what it means. (Though I wonder how a 4-hour shift can be a drag).
Compare the opening verse of “Never” Working from 11:00 to 7:00 every night
Ought to make life a drag
And I know that ain’t right.
to the opening verse of “Since I’ve Been Loving You”
Working from 7:00 to 11:00 every night
It really makes life a drag.
I don’t think that’s right.

Mosley laments working the graveyard shift (“working from 11:00 to 7:00 every night”), Robert Plant turns the numbers around (“Working from 7:00 to 11:00 every night”). Plant is either spending pretty much every waking hour at work or else he’s complaining about working a four-hour evening shift –

These lines from the song were debated on a website, and I found this explanation interesting.:

Ref. https://www.lyricinterpretations.com/led-zeppelin/since-ive-been-loving-you.
i disagree with most of the misinterpretations. i believe page is referring to a serious committed relation like marriage etc and the line 'working from 7 to 11 every night' actually refers to the time he spends with his lover/wife arguing or possibly fighting. He is frustrated with the recurring fights and the misunderstandings etc and the continuous mind torture he receives from her end.
On a very basic level the song is portraying how a man goes through a failed relationship/marriage and how he deals with it. It also hints of a possible adultery from his wife's end. Repetition and the importance of the line 'working from 7 to 11' in the said song conforms to the above analysis.


As mentioned by Fumblefingers, seven-eleven has cone to mean long hours because of the convenience stores in the USA. The phrase is even spreading to other parts of the world such as New Zealand and Australia.
So, saying that one works from 7 to 11 is like a metaphor for working long hours.  Used in literature, the alliteration also helps.

I disagree, at least in the United States. I've never heard of that.

While the origin of the name is true, I'm not aware of any usage outside of the brand name. If you have evidence for this idea, please edit to include it.

Do you know when the song was released? Led Zeppelin is a British band, were there 7-elevens in the UK  back then? Do some simple research before speculating on something without supporting evidence. -1
